# Eigen decomposition in Scala

Tags: scala, breeze, linear-algebra

I want to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a positive semi-definite matrix in Scala (using Breeze), and I'm stuck.

From the Breeze linear algebra library reference example:

```
val A = DenseMatrix((9.0,0.0,0.0),(0.0,82.0,0.0),(0.0,0.0,25.0))
val EigSym(lambda, evs) = eigSym(A)
```

First of all in my program A is a covariance matrix:

```
val EigSym(lambda,evs)=EigSym(cov)
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
Error:(120, 34) not enough arguments for method apply: (eigenvalues: V, eigenvectors: M)breeze.linalg.eigSym.EigSym[V,M] in object EigSym.
Unspecified value parameter eigenvectors.
    val EigSym(lambda,evs)=EigSym(cov)
                                 ^
```

What should the other argument be?

Secondly,  can anyone explain for me why we need "EigSym(lambda,evs)" on the left hand side (I'm new to Scala, and expect just (lambda,evs)).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first issue is that `eigSym` and `EigSym` are different. `eigSym` is an object that has an `apply` method that accepts a `DenseMatrix`, so we can write `eigSym(A)`, which is syntactic sugar (provided by Scala—it's not Breeze-specific) for `eigSym.apply(A)`.

So the following will work:

```
import breeze.linalg._, eigSym.EigSym

val A = DenseMatrix((9.0,0.0,0.0),(0.0,82.0,0.0),(0.0,0.0,25.0))
val EigSym(lambda, evs) = eigSym(A)
```

The `val EigSym(lambda, evs) = ...` part uses the fact that `EigSym` is [a case class](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/149b3655977eb9dea38b53a18b83d0a4e0e08d41/math/src/main/scala/breeze/linalg/functions/eig.scala#L90), and that `eigSym` returns an `EigSym`. The `EigSym` on the left-hand side of the definition deconstructs the case class and defines new `lambda` and `evs` variables that are assigned to `EigSym`'s two members. You could also write the following:

```
val es = eigSym(A)
val lambda = es.eigenvalues
val evs = es.eigenvectors
```

This is equivalent, except that it also defines an `es` variable, and it's a little more noisy and verbose.

More generally, the `val X(a, b, c) = ...` syntax works if the `X` object has an `unapply` method that takes arguments of the right types (and the `X` is then sometimes called an "extractor" in Scala). Scala case classes have an `unapply` method automatically generated for them by the compiler.

That's a lot of syntactic sugar, though, and it's perfectly reasonable to use the more verbose form of assignment—just remember that if you see this kind of syntax in other people's code, you should either look for a case class definition or an `unapply` method if you want to figure out what's going on.